boost managed_mapped_file does not allocate type on cache aligned memory
I have below sample code, the find_or_construct() returned pointer(ptr) is not aligned to the cache line.
Is there a way to force boost find_or_construct to allocate objects on aligned memory?
struct alignas( 64 ) type_t {
  int arr[1000];
};

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
typedef bip::basic_managed_mapped_file<
    char,
    bip::rbtree_best_fit<bip::mutex_family, bip::offset_ptr<void>,
                         64>,
    bip::iset_index>
    managed_mapped_file_aligned;

inline void allocate() {
  managed_mapped_file_aligned mmf( bip::open_only,
                                   "/mnt/hugepage/test_boost_shm" );

  type_t* ptr = mmf.find_or_construct<type_t>( "test name" )();
  // ptr is not CACHE aligned
}


To the latter "Can it be forced" - for sure because you can swap out the allocation manager (subclass it to add your logic). However I'd report this issue as a bug.

And regardless of whether it's a bug or not, you can just workaround yourself. assuming that the "alignas(64)" is in bytes, just allocate a simple chunk of bytes with the required size +63, adjust the returned pointer, and do a placement new at the proper location. Plus some resource tracking since your byte buffer and the actual object are now two separate entities.

@ChristianStieber I know that I can ask for a bigger space and use the aligned memory. I just feel it's annoying that I have to do all these stuff across processes.

@billz still, as I said, feel free to suggest the change to boost; don't care whether you're phrasing it as a nice-to-have new feature or a bug. However, they will (likely) not do anything right away, so you'll have to either pause your project, possibly for a long time, or implement a workaround anyway...

@ChristianStieber thanks for the suggestion, I did the same way you suggested for now.
